# Findout the final answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

Sometimes I'll have a similar question to one that's already been asked and answered.  But the user hasn't accepted any given answer.  I'm then curious to understand what the user (with the question) finally decided to go with for the particular problem at hand.

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862598/list-of-uml-state-machine-diagram-to-java-code-generation-software)

I wanted to know which tool the user finalized on.

Currently, it's not a good idea to ask questions on the forums like "Hey, what did you finally do?  How did you implement it?" and neither is there a way to message the user privately.

So my question is: can this be currently addressed in any way or are there any plans in the future to solve this kind of situation?

Comment: You could post a comment on the question, asking if the issue had been resolved, or if it was still an *open* question, but really, why do you care what that particular user settled on, other than curiousity?  The community has given an indication of it's preference, through the upvotes...

Comment: @forsvarir - posting a comment requires 50+ rep, but apart from that it's a good idea.

Comment: @ChrisF: That's a good point.  I keep forgetting that the comment threshold can act as a barrier...

Comment: @forsvarir: We primarily require 50 reps for that kind of thing because it's considered noise. We don't want everybody that comes along from a Google search posting those comments to every question.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I understand the reasoning behind the rep limit (although I think it could be achieved in different ways).  I think sometimes it can be hard to disassociate a question from the user asking it, particularly when you’ve got a similar problem + want to know what they did / if it worked (as in this case), or while you’re pinging questions/answers back and forth trying to get to a solution (which is where I tend to be).  Perhaps that’s one of the elements of reputation / privileges I haven’t considered...